# What type of switch would switch a Load between two different power sources? (12V DC)

Tags: battery, switches

I want a switch to let me choose whether 12V DC (10A max)  power to a wire is coming from Vehicle  (DC out) power or from an Auxiliary battery.

I think this would be a DPDT On-On switch.

What's the proper name for that sort of switch (or any suggestions of specific switches)?

Answer (score 2):

Boats often have a switch like that. You should be able to search “dual battery switch” or similar.

Note that those have an additional position you might not want, which is “both” or “all” where both sources are connected. This is to allow the batteries to charge while the engine is running.

[image: perko battery switch]

Comment: Switches like that one are overkill for 10A - they will likely do 100's of A and are priced accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a common GROUND connection, then you need a 10A (or higher) SPDT switch.

Specific product or shopping questions are off-topic, but just about any auto parts store or major online retailers will have suitable switches fitting this description:

12VDC, 10A, SPDT Toggle Switch